# loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getSocketFactory()

Tags: java, maven, jboss6.x

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [gts.efx.web.login.LogInController]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving
>   method
>   "javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getSocketFactory()Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory;"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class,
>   org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory, and the class
>   loader (instance of ) for resolved class,
>   javax/net/ssl/SSLContext, have different Class objects for the type
>   javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory used in the signature

This error comes up after adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If i don't add this dependency i get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
        at gts.efx.web.login.LogInController.<init>(LogInController.java:51)
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because adding that dependency puts two implementations of

```
javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory
```

On the classpath. And they are not compatible.

You give very little info about the platform you are using, but it seems to be JBOSS.

It would seem that server is not compatible with the apache httpclient library.

Comment: It is indeed. It could not be resolved hence had to switch to Spring RestTemplate to code for my rest client.

Comment: Also new to RestTemplate hence any clear info would be appreciated.